# Strange blocking behaviour with gevent/grequests over HTTPS

Tags: python, https, gevent, greenlets, grequests

The following code sends a request every 200ms and should handle the responses asynchronously whenever they come.

Over HTTP it works as expected - a request is sent every 200ms and the response callback is called independently whenever a response arrives. Over HTTPS however, the requests get significantly delayed whenever a response arrives (even though my response handler does no work). The response callback seems to be called twice for each request, once with a zero-length response (edit: this is because of a redirect and seems unrelated to the blocking issue, thanks Padraic).

What could be causing this blocking behaviour over HTTPS? (`www.bbc.co.uk` is just an example that's geographically far from me, but it happens with all servers I've tested).

**grequests_test.py**

```
import time
import sys
import grequests
import gevent

def cb(res, **kwargs):
    print("**** Response", time.time(), len(res.text))

for i in range(10):
    unsent = grequests.get(sys.argv[1], hooks={'response': cb})
    print("Request", time.time())
    grequests.send(unsent, grequests.Pool(1))
    gevent.sleep(0.2)
gevent.sleep(5)
```

**`$ ipython2 grequests_test.py 'http://www.bbc.co.uk'`** (expected result)

```
('Request', 1459050191.499266)
('Request', 1459050191.701466)
('Request', 1459050191.903223)
('Request', 1459050192.10403)
('Request', 1459050192.305626)
('**** Response', 1459050192.099185, 179643)
('Request', 1459050192.506476)
('**** Response', 1459050192.307869, 179643)
('Request', 1459050192.707745)
('**** Response', 1459050192.484711, 179643)
('Request', 1459050192.909376)
('**** Response', 1459050192.696583, 179643)
('Request', 1459050193.110528)
('**** Response', 1459050192.870476, 179643)
('Request', 1459050193.311601)
('**** Response', 1459050193.071679, 179639)
('**** Response', 1459050193.313615, 179680)
('**** Response', 1459050193.4959, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050193.687054, 179680)
('**** Response', 1459050193.902827, 179639)
```

**`ipython2 grequests_test.py 'https://www.bbc.co.uk'`** (requests are sent late)

```
('Request', 1459050203.24336)
('Request', 1459050203.44473)
('**** Response', 1459050204.423302, 0)
('Request', 1459050204.424748) <------------- THIS REQUEST TIME IS LATE
('**** Response', 1459050205.294426, 0)
('Request', 1459050205.296722)
('Request', 1459050205.497924)
('**** Response', 1459050206.456572, 0)
('Request', 1459050206.457875)
('**** Response', 1459050207.363188, 0)
('**** Response', 1459050208.247189, 0)
('Request', 1459050208.249579)
('**** Response', 1459050208.250645, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050208.253638, 179643)
('Request', 1459050208.451083)
('**** Response', 1459050209.426556, 0)
('Request', 1459050209.428032)
('**** Response', 1459050209.428929, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050210.331425, 0)
('**** Response', 1459050211.247793, 0)
('Request', 1459050211.251574)
('**** Response', 1459050211.252321, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050211.25519, 179680)
('**** Response', 1459050212.397186, 0)
('**** Response', 1459050213.299109, 0)
('**** Response', 1459050213.588854, 179588)
('**** Response', 1459050213.590434, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050213.593731, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050213.90507, 179643)
('**** Response', 1459050213.909386, 179643)
```

Notice that the first response appears to arrive long after the next request *should* have been sent but wasn't. Why didn't the sleep return, and the next request get sent, before that first response arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current iteration of grequests contains the following:

```
from gevent import monkey as curious_george
curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

The offending part is `select=False` - removing this or manually calling `monkey.patch_select()` solves the problem. I am not sure if this has other side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The extra responses and the 0 length responses are easily explained, if you add a `print(res.status_code)` you will see a lot of 301's as  in the case of `https://www.bbc.co.uk` you get redirected to `http://www.bbc.co.uk` so that is why you see extras responses and `0` returned for the `len(res.text)`, you can see the output below:

```
In [11]: def cb(res, **kwargs):
   ....:         print(res.status_code)
   ....:         print("**** Response", time.time(), len(res.text))
   ....:     

In [12]: for i in range(10):
   ....:         unsent = grequests.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk", hooks={'response': cb})
   ....:         print("Request", time.time())
   ....:         grequests.send(unsent, grequests.Pool(1))
   ....:         gevent.sleep(0.2)
   ....: gevent.sleep(5)
   ....: 
('Request', 1459368704.32843)
301
('**** Response', 1459368704.616453, 0)
('Request', 1459368704.618786)
301
('**** Response', 1459368704.937159, 0)
('Request', 1459368704.941069)
200
('**** Response', 1459368704.943034, 141486)
301
('**** Response', 1459368705.496423, 0)
('Request', 1459368705.498991)
200
('**** Response', 1459368705.50162, 141448)
301
('**** Response', 1459368705.784145, 0)
('Request', 1459368705.785769)
200
('**** Response', 1459368705.786772, 141486)
301
('**** Response', 1459368706.110865, 0)
('Request', 1459368706.114921)
200
('**** Response', 1459368706.116124, 141448)
301
('**** Response', 1459368706.396807, 0)
('Request', 1459368706.400795)
200
301
('**** Response', 1459368706.756861, 0)
('Request', 1459368706.76069)
200
('**** Response', 1459368706.763268, 141448)
('**** Response', 1459368706.488708, 141448)
301
('**** Response', 1459368707.065011, 0)
('Request', 1459368707.069128)
200
('**** Response', 1459368707.071981, 141448)
301
('**** Response', 1459368707.366737, 0)
('Request', 1459368707.370713)
200
('**** Response', 1459368707.373597, 141448)
301
('**** Response', 1459368707.73689, 0)
200
('**** Response', 1459368707.743815, 141448)
200
('**** Response', 1459368707.902499, 141448)
```

If we run the same code using a site that serves over https, `https://www.google.ie/` in this example:

```
In [14]: for i in range(10):
   ....:         unsent = grequests.get("https://www.google.ie/", hooks={'response': cb})
   ....:         print("Request", time.time())
   ....:         grequests.send(unsent, grequests.Pool(1))
   ....:         gevent.sleep(0.2)
   ....: gevent.sleep(5)
   ....: 
('Request', 1459368895.525717)
200
('**** Response', 1459368895.838453, 19682)
('Request', 1459368895.884151)
200
('**** Response', 1459368896.168789, 19650)
('Request', 1459368896.22553)
200
('**** Response', 1459368896.491304, 19632)
('Request', 1459368896.542206)
200
('**** Response', 1459368896.808875, 19650)
('Request', 1459368896.850575)
200
('**** Response', 1459368897.144725, 19705)
('Request', 1459368897.173744)
200
('**** Response', 1459368897.45713, 19649)
('Request', 1459368897.491821)
200
('**** Response', 1459368897.761675, 19657)
('Request', 1459368897.792373)
200
('**** Response', 1459368898.331791, 19683)
('Request', 1459368898.350483)
200
('**** Response', 1459368898.836108, 19713)
('Request', 1459368898.855729)
200
('**** Response', 1459368899.148171, 19666)
```

You will see the behaviour is different. We get 10 responses and no `0` length responses. You should check the `status_code` in your function to verify you get what you want. The example above explains what you see for the bbc  site and most likely what is happening for the others.

Comment: Ok, that explains the 0 length responses. You're right, it doesn't happen on other domains. Any idea about the blocking?